# Is there a way to keep a DataGridView row selected when the user clicks on a cell in another row?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

The `DataGridView` control allows you to click the row headers and select the rows (the whole row is highlighted), or use the mouse and click and drag to select multiple rows, etc. to select all of them.

Anyway, I need the rows to stay selected if the user decides to click on a cell somewhere in the `DataGridView`. So, if the user clicks on a cell in one of the selected rows, the selected rows should stay highlighted. If the user clicks a cell in a different, *unselected* row, all the currently selected cells should stay highlighted. As a matter of fact, I don't want the row selection to change *at all* unless they use the row headers.

Is this something that's easy to configure, or am I in for a few days of hacking?

Comment: Ok, well, I thought of different way to achieve what I wanted. You guys don't have to bother answering this one anymore! Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Best practice is to post your own solution and accept it - you may be helping someone in the future.

Comment: Meanwhile you'd be better off simply training your users that when they click a cell they are selecting a row.  They should learn that quickly - it's default behaviour.

Comment: No it isn't. You have to have it on FullRowSelect for that to be true. The little triangle on the rowheader doesn't mean the row is in the collection of selected rows. By default I think its set to RowHeaderSelect. Anyway, the default behavior of the datagridview is utter BS, I've really changed it alot

Comment: Anyway, I haven't solved this problem... I only changed my design so I didn't have to solve it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easy to configure. Spend a few days with the `DataGridView` control, and you'll notice that *nothing* about it is easy to configure, unless the developers happened to decide to expose it as a property. And only the simplest of things are exposed this way, so don't waste too much time looking.

Of course, it *is* possible. I've spent way too much of my life subclassing the `DataGridView` control and overriding built-in behavior that strikes me as stupid. But I really don't recommend it to anyone.

More to the point, you should also seriously reconsider whether you even *want* to make this particular change. I would have no idea what was going on if software started to do that. I'd immediately suspect that my shift key or mouse button were stuck and try banging them unstuck. The next step would be restarting my computer. Overall, not a very positive user experience. This isn't the way that the control behaves for a reason. Do consider very carefully what it actually means *semantically* for a cell to be highlighted—generally, the implication is that you can change the value of or delete all selected cells at once. If that's *not* how your implementation is going to work, you probably shouldn't do it in the first place.

Comment: It's too late. I've subclassed the datagridview too and I've already fixed a great many annoying behaviors of it and added some new ones that were useful to me. I've figured out how to add my own controls in there... I can't get away from the damn DGV now. And the more deeply I delve into its workings the harder it seems to be to find help about it. Ah well.

Comment: @IsaacB: Yeah, that's because the DGV is kind of a bastard control that no one wants to use. Everyone doing anything non-trivial ends up reimplementing the damn thing, but certainly doesn't want to spend their time helping anyone else do the same. Painful memories, I suppose. If you want to go through with this, you have no choice but to take *all* of the selection behavior into your own hands. Prevent the control from adding cells, rows, or columns to the selected items properties, and add them yourself in an override of the `OnRowHeaderMouseClick` method.

Comment: `"I've spent way too much of my life subclassing the DataGridView control"` I hear ya!

Answer (score 2):

I would say its **not a good idea** to to this and its unwanted behavior  from users perspective you will need to teach them that your rows get selected only by row headers not by clicking on them (believe me they will be frustrated). In a way you are refraining the user from selecting the rows at all.

That said, if you are keen to go on this design then you will need to do it yourself. GridView doesn't have any built behaviour for this. You can fiddle with RowChanged events and CanSelect properties  &  do some overriding.

And then there's a [**RowHeaderMouseClick**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx) event you can utilize for Row  Selection from Row Header.

Comment: No, its not too much of an issue. My user base is 4-5 people at most. They're already used to clicking the row headers for deleting multiple rows anyway. The fact that the row is selected by clicking on a cell has no meaningful use in my program right now. I'm not giving anything up by getting rid of it.

Comment: @IsaacB: Ah, do you have the `DataGridViewSelectionMode` property set to "FullRowSelect"? That would cause clicking on a single cell to select the entire row. If that's not what you want, change that property to something like "RowHeaderSelect". (All the possible values are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86.aspx).)

Comment: @IsaacB well then i have mentioned about how to that by utilizing RowHeaderMouseClick event..good luck :)

Comment: @Cody Gray `RowHeaderSelect` mode still selects the cell if clicked on the cells.. OP still need to override this behavior

Comment: @Shekhar: No, it doesn't. Clicking one of the cells selects that cell, but it does *not* select the entire row. It's not clear if that will actually solve the problem discussed in the question, but it might be an answer to his last comment.

Comment: No, the selection mode doesn't help me much. The real problem is how the user can interact with the buttons and checkboxes and things in the gridview without deselecting the rows already selected. Thats why I want the selection of the rows to be done only with the rowheader. Setting it to rowheaderselect sounds like it would be the solution except clicking on a cell deselects the selected rows.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to circumvent this using, er... DataGridView subclassing, sorry.

This can be done cleanly, adding a couple of delegate before and after the internal mechanism that unselect them:

```
class SimpleDataGridView : DataGridView {

    public Action<DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs> BeforeCellMouseDown;
    public Action<DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs> AfterCellMouseDown;

    protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        if(BeforeCellMouseDown != null)
            BeforeCellMouseDown(e);

        base.OnCellMouseDown(e);

        if(AfterCellMouseDown != null)
            AfterCellMouseDown(e);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it this way, in your constructor. Replace "yourCondition" by the way you want to determine wether the selection has to be kept or not.

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> sel = null;

dataGridView1.BeforeCellMouseDown = 
    e => {
        if (yourCondition)
            sel = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>();
        else
            sel = null;
    };

dataGridView1.AfterCellMouseDown = 
    e => {
        if(sel != null) {
            foreach(var row in sel)
                row.Selected = true;
        }
    };
```